# TcpClient/TcpServer/Listener, Server stops reading or client stops after 30 seconds

Tags: c#, tcpclient, streamreader, streamwriter, tcplistener

**Client**

```
class Client
{
    public TcpClient client;
    public StreamWriter server;
    public ServerPlayer serverPlayer;
    public Player player;
    public void Connect(Player p)
    {
        player = p;
        serverPlayer = new ServerPlayer();
        client = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        client.Connect("Don't wory my IPV4 Is Here", 8888);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        server = new StreamWriter(stream);
        Timer t = new Timer(Send, null, 0, 10);
    }
    public void Send(Object o)
    {
        server.WriteLine("Hello I am bob");
        server.Flush();

    }

}
```

**Server**

```
class TcpServerConnection
{
    private static TcpListener tcpListener;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
        tcpListener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server started.");

        while (true)
        {
            //blocks until a client has connected to the server
            TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //create a thread to handle communication
            //with connected client
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }

    private static void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            StreamReader server = new StreamReader(clientStream);
            Console.WriteLine(server.ReadLine());
        }


}
}
```

**Problem**

Track of events:

> Started!
>
> Hello I am bob
>
> Hello I am bob
>
> (Many Hello I am bobs later)
>
> Hello I am bob
>
> (Hello I am bobs just stopped)
>
> (About 30 seconds)

Don't know if it because the client stops sending or server stops receiving or both!? But once this is ran about 30 seconds into this the server stops getting the send information. No error is thrown simply it just doesn't send.

Comment: ugh those while loops look iffy. try removing the while(true) on your server. if you are trying to keep the app alive use a console.readline at the end of your main block. those while loops are going to try and spin up a whole heck of a lot of threads.

Comment: @kmacdonald If you think its stopping because while(true) Then please suggest something to replace it with? Sorry i am quite new,

Comment: @kmacdonald Maybe a object for each client then every 10ms on a timer I go through every client and receive data in List<client> ?

Comment: In your Client, move the declaration of your Timer `t` up to class level with the rest of the variables so it doesn't get garbage collected.  Same thing in your Server; create a `List<Thread>` at class level to hold references to each Thread created.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Good idea. Our team is just going off for the day. I will try this tomorrow. But with my luck I have very high expectations for this not to work.

Comment: How do you know there are no exceptions? Set the debugger to halt on all exceptions. What's the timer interval?

Comment: @usr 10MS Interval breaks in about 30 seconds. And 1000ms (1 second) breaks in about 30 seconds to 1 minute. Which makes no sense. Also I will try with more break points and trying to find exceptions but I can't find any, (No try and catch statements used)

Comment: @Idle_Mind No difference at all. But made neater code and the server should run better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out it was my internet. After my google-fu. I set my port for my server to be TCP open. Found out my router was getting suspicious after a spam of messages going into a random port. IP:IPV4  PORT:8888  SETTINGS:OPEN

Answer (score 0):

Ok in your ServerConnection object the first while loop is fine.  but the one in your handler is going to cause some problems try this:

```
private static void HandleClientComm(object client)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    using(var stream = new StreamReader(clientStream))
    {
       while (stream.Peek() >= 0) 
       {
           Console.WriteLine(server.ReadLine());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still stopped after a while. About 30 seconds it stopped sending:

Comment: can you put a breakpoint in send and see if you are still getting in there? 10 ms is a short interval.  something must be stopping.

Comment: Tried with 1000ms. Took about a min. Makes no sense why a minute. Breakpoint nothing is null. And all is good.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating one and only one connection to the Server, and then sending messages constantly in the Client, accordingly when handling the client messages in the Server program, you should accept a TcpClient and then read messages in a loop, instead of accepting a Tcplient and reading a message all in a loop.

```
private static void HandleClientComm(object client)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    StreamReader server = new StreamReader(clientStream);
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(server.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: @ElliotBewey Cool! So it's not a coding problem.

Comment: yup :D.. Thank god for that.